# Как заменить табы (\t) на 4 пробела в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть простенький *редактор кода* сделаной с Tkinter'ом с помощью `Text`
При этом если нажать `TAB` то появится как ни странно таб
Но мне нужны иммено 4 пробела вместо таба

Comment: Пожалуйта, добавте исходный код к вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо перехватить событие нажатия клавиши <kbd>Tab</kbd>. И в нём вставлять в тестовый виджет 4 пробела. Также из обработчика вернуть `break` чтобы не сработал обработчик по-умолчанию.

```
import tkinter as tk

def tab_pressed(arg):
    #print("tab")
    text.insert(tk.INSERT, " "*4)
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

text.bind("<Tab>", tab_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```